# Concat string in SQL Select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

I have the following TSQL:

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    CAST('' as XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("Content"))', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') + '=' as Content, 
    Name
FROM Files
ORDER BY Id
```

The character '=' is not being added at the end of the column Content value. I also tried:

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    CONCAT(CAST('' as XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("Content"))', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), '=') as Content, 
    Name
FROM Files
ORDER BY Id
```

Same problem ... The character '=' is not added at the end of the string.

What am I missing?

Comment: RDBMS (I assume SqlServer but I've been burned before)  and Version please?

Comment: Yes, MSFT SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The character '=' is not being added at the end of the column

Sure it is.  SSMS may be truncating the value.  But you shouldn't be adding '=' to the end in the first place.  That's part of the base64 spec, and the xml.value() will add '=' or '==' to pad the value as necessary.  Adding '=' to the end will produce an invalid base64 string, eg:

```
use tempdb
go
drop table if exists Files
go
create table Files(id int primary key, name varchar(200), Content varbinary(max))

go
insert into Files(id,name,Content) values (1,'1',0x9789798d7987907a09797a987908790787897b0987d9087097e09879087d907907097097a0c0909890809789798798789798707097090)


SELECT 
    Id, 
    CAST('' as XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("Content"))', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') + '=' as Content, 
    Name
FROM Files
ORDER BY Id

/*
CXiXmNeYeQegl5eph5CHkHh4l7CYfZCHCX4Jh5CH2QeQcJcJegwJCYkICXiXmHmHiXmHBwlwkA===
*/
```

Here's a sample to compare .NET and SQL Server's base64 encoding:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace netcore3test
{
    class File
    {
        public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var maxLen = 1024 * 1024;

            using var con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=tempdb;integrated security=true");
            con.Open();

            var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"

with q as (select @buf Content)
select CAST('' as XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column(""Content""))', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') base64string
from q

";
            var pBuf = cmd.Parameters.Add("@buf", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);

            var rand = new Random(0);
;
            for (int len = 0; len < maxLen; len++)
            {
                var buf = new byte[len];
                rand.NextBytes(buf);
                pBuf.Value = buf;

                var netBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buf);
                var sqlBase64 = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                var json = @$"{{""Content"" : ""{sqlBase64}"" }}";
                var  File = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<File>(json);
                var sqlBuf = File.Content;

                if (!buf.SequenceEqual(sqlBuf) || netBase64 != sqlBase64)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Fail {netBase64} {sqlBase64}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine(sqlBase64);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand but in some rows I get an == in other I don't get any = at the end. What is strange is I then export the data to Json and try to deserialise it to Byte[] using C#'s ASP.NET Core 3 System Json Deserialiser and I get the error on the row that has no =:  `Cannot decode JSON text that is not encoded as valid Base64 to bytes.`. But when I add the = at the end to the rows that have no equal then I do not get the error anymore. Isn't this strange?

Comment: To deserialise I am using: `Byte[] json = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path); List<File> files = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<File>>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(json));`

Comment: SQL Server and .NET agree on the base64 endoding.  You've got a bug somewhere.  Why are you calling Encoding.GetString(json)?  The JSON should already be a string.

Comment: I am reading the JSON from a file using `Byte[] content = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path);` which returns a Byte[]